# Finding array data in worksheet values

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table sort of like this:

```
Pendergrass (606)-663-4567
Rich        (606)-667-4567
Scott       (606)-987-4567
Dennis      (606)-233-4567
David       (606)-888-4567
Red         (606)-567-4567
Wendy       (606)-765-4567
Todd        (606)-677-4567
Andrea      (606)-780-3451
Caroline    (606)-992-7865
```

and the code I'm using looks like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, bFound As Boolean, rFound As Range
    Dim a As Long, aNames As Variant

    aNames = Array("David", "Andrea", "Caroline")

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        'If ws.Name <> Worksheets("Report").Name Then
        If ws.Name = "Sheet1" Then
            With ws.Range("A1:E30").Cells
                For a = LBound(aNames) To UBound(aNames)
                    Set rFound = .Find(What:=aNames(a), MatchCase:=False, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchFormat:=False)
                    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                        bFound = True
                        With Worksheets("Report")
                            .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = rFound.Value
                        End With
                    End If
                Next a
            End With
        End If
    Next ws

    If Not bFound Then
        MsgBox "None of the sheets contains the names " & Chr(10) & _
            "'" & Join(aNames, "', '") & "' in cells A1:E30.", vbInformation, "Not Found"
    End If

End Sub
```

I would like if to take the numbers of `David`, `Andrea` and `Caroline` and put them any where in the `Report` page. This only grabs one.

Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong with this code?

Comment: Andrea has 2 phone numbers - did you mean to exclude Caroline?

Comment: Yes haha sorry. The last name was suppose to be Caroline.

Comment: What is this abomination people are doing to my question ?!

Comment: Since some have modified the question, for clarification: You are currently grabbing the name and putting it in the report properly, and you just want to get the number as well?

Comment: My edits were superficial - changed title to be searchable rather than specific to OPs variable name; small formatting changes; added a specific question - because there wasn't one - just a problem description.

Comment: np. OP's question is still unclear. What is the meaning of "It only grabs one", unmodified the code grabs the names correctly, but not the associated number.

Comment: you have a "dangerous" `With Worksheets("Report")` nested under a `With ws.Range("A1:E30").Cells` which is another worksheet - stay away from those

Comment: Actually, thank you to the people that edited my original question. I got the help I needed. Sorry too

Comment: Is there a youtube channel you can suggest to help learn VBA like y'all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below.

However, not sure why you are looping through all the sheets with `For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` , if at the following line you are checking `If ws.Name = "Sheet1" Then`.

You can replace the lines below (remove a `For`, a `With` and `If`) :

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws
        'If ws.Name <> Worksheets("Report").Name Then
        If .Name = "Sheet1" Then
            With .Range("A1:E30").Cells
```

with a simple:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E30").Cells
```

**Code**

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, bFound As Boolean, rFound As Range
    Dim a As Long, aNames As Variant

    aNames = Array("David", "Andrea", "Caroline")

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            'If ws.Name <> Worksheets("Report").Name Then
            If .Name = "Sheet1" Then
                With .Range("A1:E30").Cells
                    For a = LBound(aNames) To UBound(aNames)
                        Set rFound = .Find(What:=aNames(a), MatchCase:=False, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchFormat:=False)
                        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                            bFound = True
                            Worksheets("Report").Cells(Worksheets("Report").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = rFound.Value
                            Worksheets("Report").Cells(Worksheets("Report").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(, 1) = rFound.Offset(, 1).Value
                        End If
                    Next a
                End With
            End If
        End With
    Next ws

    If Not bFound Then
        MsgBox "None of the sheets contains the names " & Chr(10) & _
            "'" & Join(aNames, "', '") & "' in cells A1:E30.", vbInformation, "Not Found"
    End If

End Sub
```